# Connection to cloudant using Java

Tags: java, cloudant

I am currently referring to this [github](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant) project to connect to cloudant using java. I am not sure where I am going wrong but am not able to connect

I am facing the following error message as shown in my console
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudant/client/api/ClientBuilder
at com.controller.DisplayCheck(controller.java:61)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudant.client.api.ClientBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at com.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)`

Here are my dependencies that i declared in my POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudant-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
    <version>1.34</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.littleshoot</groupId>
    <artifactId>littleproxy</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   

    </dependencies>
```

Below is my piece of code that I am trying to test from my controller.

```
CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account("account")
                .username("Id")
                .password("pas")
                .build();

        System.out.println("Server Version: " + client.serverVersion());
        List<String> databases = client.getAllDbs();
        System.out.println("All my databases : ");
        for ( String db : databases ) {
            System.out.println(db);
        }
```

Below are the imports used

```
import com.cloudant.client.api.ClientBuilder;
import com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient;
```

Comment: Fixed this. Required another jar file for http which was not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

From the github link that you posted, you should have these two dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
  <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp-urlconnection</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I see some sort of a resemblance to them in your dependencies, but its not quite them and thus I cant be sure what they are.